# Есть ли более удобный способ работать с View элементами в Android?

Tags: java, android, javafx

После JavaFX, где элементы окна можно получить с помощью магии, прикрепив в классе контроллера (активити в андроиде) поля с аннотацией, например,

```
@FXML
ListView<String> ciList; //название поля должно совпасть с ID компонента
```

В анроиде приходится каждый раз искать вьюшку аж вот так:

```
TextView twBurnTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw_burn_time);
```

Ещё одно неудобство, что в FX один ID name в XML и в коде, а здесь конвешены разные, в XML нужно писать как_в_html.
Не придумали ли ещё аннотацию, которая бы помогла разработчикам меньше писать, а больше работать?

Comment: Еще можно вспомнить [Data binding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#data_binding_layout_files) - реализация паттерна MVVM в Android

Comment: C использованием AndroidAnnotation появился побочный эффект - перестали наполняться выпадающие списки. `E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.<init>`

Answer (score 3):

"View injection"

### Android Annotations:

```
@ViewById 
TextView tw_burn_time;
```

Работал с ButterKnifer, Dagger2, но пример выше кажется больше подходит для того, что вы хотите на данный момент.

Comment: Я знал, что я не один так хочу :)

Answer (score 3):

[AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/) Мощная штука

[Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) Биндит вьюхи

[Icepick](https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick) SaveInstanceState без боли

Comment: Спасибо. Это замечательная новость! Первое - это то, что нужно. Там не только вьюхи можно биндить.